# Goland can't auto import "fmt"?

Tags: go, goland

Goland *(version 2021.2, on **Linux**)* can't auto import "fmt", when add a line of code that use fmt's functions.
I need to add `import "fmt"` by hand.
But seems it doesn't have problem with other built-in go packages.

It that a bug, or a special design ?

BTW, the similar issue occur for 3rd-party package `"github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"`, the auto import will hint several options to import `assert`, but the above one is always not in the list in my case, had to `import` by hand.

**Screenshot**:

[image: fmt import hint in goland]

---

### @Update: Cause of issue & solution found

**Issue:**
[image: imports setting in goland]

**Solution**: just remove the 2 line, then import works immediately.

Thanks to `s0xzwasd`'s comment under question, and `jinseok.oh`'s answer, which actually mentioned the setting.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem in GoLand 2021.2 based on your description.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I'm using linux. It has happened every time for quite a long time for me.

Comment: Are you using a qualified identifier of a function _exported_ by `fmt`? For unexported functions, what you're observing is expected behaviour.

Comment: @jub0bs I'm just using `fmt.Printf("hello\n")`, and golang can't auto import `fmt`

Comment: Do you have any entries configured under _File | Settings | Go | GOPATH_ or _File | Settings | Go | Imports_? Are you using Go modules?

Comment: @s0xzwasd `File | Settings | Go | Imports` I saw that 2 packages exactly in the list .. after removing it, the issue is solved .. I don't know when that 2 packages were added there .. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Global Println() function and also fmt.Println() function()

If you writh Println and press ctl+space only then IDE will set autocomplete Println().

/// add

[image]

Also you have to check this. Is there any exclucde from import and completion?

If doesn't exist, then my last advise is doing invalidate caches/ restart

[image]